# Azure Cli update variable with JSON object in powershell script

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell, azure-cli

I am trying to update Azure pipeline group variable from within a PowerShell script using the az cli.

I have the command updating the variable but its modifying the json and removing all the quotes (")

so instead of updating variable from
`{"a": "a"}`
to
`{"a": "b"}`

it updates it to `{a: b}`

I am running the following command

```
$json = ConvertTo-Json $a -Compress
Write-Host $json
az pipelines variable-group variable update --group-id 236 --name MyJson --detect true --secret false --value $json
```

The outut of the `write-host` is

```
{"a": "b"}
```

Output of the the `az pipelines variable-group variable update` is

```
{
 "MyJson": {
   "isSecret": null,
   "value": "{a:b}"
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I get it to update without modifying the JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So while @charles works when passing the data straight to the command like that, we are using variables.

While I understand what's going on here, still think the az command could handle this better.

So to get this to work I had to do a replace on the string and replace all `"` with `\"`

Annoying that this has to be done but it works, so my final commands look like this:

```
$new_json = $json.replace("`"", "\`"")
az pipelines variable-group variable update --group-id $(VarGroupId) --name var_name --detect true --secret false --value $new_json
```

Comment: Why not accept my answer instead of adding another answer when you just copy the solution?!

Comment: The json string must contain backslashes, rather than just escaping the json to fit in the string. The answers are different.

Answer (score 1):

All the variables are stored as strings and are mutable, and it already means string when it's in the double-quotes. So it removes all the quotes inside. If you want to make the quotes also stores as the value, then you need to transfer them like this:

```
{\"a\":\"b\"}
```

Or just use single quotation marks:

```
'{"a":"b"}'
```

Finally, it will look like this:

[image]

It's not necessary to store the double-quotes as the value. So I don't recommend you do this without any special reason.

Comment: so interesting when you do it with a var put the var in `' '` doesn't work.  So I have had to do a replace and replace all the `"` with `\"` then pass it to the command